# Does a recursive disk-space-usage pie-chart web-page generator exist for Linux?

Tags: linux, disk-space

Does anyone know of a per directory ( not per user) disk space usage pie chart generator script for linux?  I want to generate a set of web pages that will give me the usage of each directory, and then you can click on the pie-chart segment and see the disk usage of that sub-directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kdirstat is a similar program for KDE.  Worst case scenario, if you don't want to do it manually, you can probably borrow the code, or even hack together an automated GUI/saver solution using DBUS.

Anyway, the generate chart type you're looking for is called a "Treemap", so that should help you to track something down.  Check out http://www.cs.umd.edu/hcil/treemap-history/

Update: Seems there are both python and ruby libraries:

http://rubytreemap.rubyforge.org/html-treemap.html

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/treemap/1.05

Presumably, you just need to read the directory entries, group them hierarchically (probably in whatever way is most natural to your language of choice; lists and dicts in python, I suppose), and then call the library to generate your output graphic.  But this is a guess; read the docs :)

Comment: kdirstat is awesome, I use it all the time. There's also a windows port, windirstat.

Answer (score 2):

The only app I'm aware of is the **Disk Usage Analyzer** (under *Applications > Accessories*) which does almost exactly what you want, but without the web page bit. You could take some screenshots or something I guess.

Comment: This Disk Usage Analyser is called than way inside the Gnome menu. It is a part of the [gnome-utils](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeUtils) package known as [Baobab](http://www.marzocca.net/linux/baobab).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on a headless server, and view the data offline, then this is a great option:

http://zevv.nl/play/code/philesight/